# How can I evaluate some URLs returned in HATEOAS format using Oracle PLSQL

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, hateoas

For eg: I have response returned as follows from a GET service. I want to evaluate URLs:
URL2.com and URL7.com further in the same process and store the result. What would be a good approach to do this. I know the method of using UTL_HTTP to do a GET call but in this case should I do a GET call for 'parent' URL and then further GET calls for all my required child requests?

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "PersonId": 1,
            "PersonNumber": "2",
            "CorrespondenceLanguage": null,
            "BloodType": null,
            "DateOfBirth": "1970-03-11",
            "DateOfDeath": null,
            "CountryOfBirth": null,
            "RegionOfBirth": null,
            "TownOfBirth": null,
            "ApplicantNumber": null,
            "CreatedBy": "",
            "CreationDate": "2018-06-21T03:46:31.499+00:00",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "LastUpdateDate": "2021-05-25T10:52:05.751+00:00",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "href": "URL1.com",
                    "name": "workers",
                    "kind": "item",
                    "properties": {
                        "changeIndicator": "X"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "URL2.com",
                    "name": "workers",
                    "kind": "item"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "child",
                    "href": "URL3.com",
                    "name": "addresses",
                    "kind": "collection"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "PersonId": 2,
            "PersonNumber": "1",
            "CorrespondenceLanguage": null,
            "BloodType": null,
            "DateOfBirth": "1969-07-04",
            "DateOfDeath": null,
            "CountryOfBirth": null,
            "RegionOfBirth": null,
            "TownOfBirth": null,
            "ApplicantNumber": null,
            "CreatedBy": "X.X",
            "CreationDate": "2020-03-06T14:05:09+00:00",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "LastUpdateDate": "2021-04-26T23:01:31.867+00:00",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "href": "URL5.com",
                    "name": "workers",
                    "kind": "item",
                    "properties": {
                        "changeIndicator": "X"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "URL6.com",
                    "name": "workers",
                    "kind": "item"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "child",
                    "href": "URL7.com",
                    "name": "addresses",
                    "kind": "collection"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "count": 25,
    "hasMore": true,
    "limit": 25,
    "offset": 0,
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "URL8",
            "name": "workers",
            "kind": "collection"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To evaluate URLs returned in HATEOAS format using Oracle PL/SQL, you can follow these steps:

1. Parse the JSON Response.
2. Iterate through the URLs
3. Make GET Requests
4. Process the Responses

Here's a sample PL/SQL script to get you started:

```
DECLARE
    l_response CLOB;
    l_json_obj APEX_JSON.T_VALUES;
    l_url VARCHAR2(4000); -- Adjust the length as needed
BEGIN
    -- Assuming l_response contains your JSON response
    -- Parse the JSON response
    APEX_JSON.PARSE(l_response);
    
    -- Iterate through the "items" array
    FOR i IN 1 .. APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'items') LOOP
        -- Get the "links" array for each item
        APEX_JSON.get_values(p_values => l_json_obj, p_path => 'items[%d].links', p0 => i);
        
        -- Iterate through the "links" array
        FOR j IN 1 .. APEX_JSON.get_count(p_values => l_json_obj) LOOP
            -- Get the URL
            APEX_JSON.get_varchar2(p_values => l_json_obj, p_path => 'href', p0 => j, p_out => l_url);
            
            -- Check if the URL is one you want to evaluate
            IF l_url = 'URL2.com' OR l_url = 'URL7.com' THEN
                -- Make a GET request to the URL using UTL_HTTP
                -- Process the response and store the result as needed
                -- You can use UTL_HTTP.REQUEST and UTL_HTTP.RESPONSE functions here
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    
    -- Clean up after parsing
    APEX_JSON.FREE_PARSE;
END;
/
```

This script will help you parse the JSON response and extract the URLs from the "links" array, and make GET requests to the URLs you're interested in.
You'll need to add error handling and further processing based on your specific requirements.